# Relative clause with "among which"

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

Which relative clause is correct

> The technology of electronic devices, which among them the most important is computer, plays an important role in people's lives.
>
> The technology of electronic devices, among which the most important is computer, plays an important role in people's lives.
>
> The technology of electronic devices, among which the computers are the most important ones, plays an important role in people's lives.

For sentence #1, I don't know if *which among them* is correct or not because it repeats *them*, which is considered to be the same *which*.

For sentence #1 and #2, I don't know if there is a noun required after *most important* or not like *the most important one*.

For sentence #2 and #3, I don't know which is the natural word-order.

Comment: The second sentence is grammatical.

Comment: @Khan Why is the third one incorrect?

Comment: The second is closest to natural English, but this question will be removed unless you can add more information why you find this confusing or difficult to understand.  Please be specific which part of the sentence gives you trouble.

Comment: And it should read: *....among which the most important is the computer,...*

Comment: The 2nd one is fine, though it should be the generic NP "the computer".

Comment: @Andrew I modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are correct, they possibly should be

> The technology of electronic devices, which among them the most important **are** computer**s**, plays an important role in people's lives.
>
> The technology of electronic devices, among which the most important is **the** computer, plays an important role in people's lives.
>
> The technology of electronic devices, among **which computers are the most important**, plays an important role in people's lives.

The second and third become most natural.